# my sub query is taking too much time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple query but it is taking too much time for execution.

query:

```
  SELECT a.primarykey, 
         a.SID, 
         a.VID, 
         a.topic, 
         a.dstart, 
         a.dstop, 
         a.vresult,
         a.dstart1,
         a.dstart2,
         ( SELECT MIN(d.vresult)
                 FROM _temp._pb_1_1_4_1 d  
                 WHERE d.dstart1 > a.dstart1                   

         ) as _DOP0 
    FROM _temp._pb_1_1_4_1 a
```

column `dstart1` is **indexed**.

`dstart1` is **Date** type column.

Please help me to optimized above query.

if I remove **`d.dstart1 > a.dstart1`** from the `WHERE` clause then query run very fast.

whenI explain the query it gives "Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)"

I want to achieve minimum value of vresult for each row.
For each row , First filter all the records which has greater value of dstart1 for the same table and then find min(vresult) for that row.

Comment: What is `WHERE 1 AND 1 AND` supposed to be doing there? Explain your schema, add sample data, explain your expected results based on that data.

Comment: Why do you have `IF(1, ..., NULL)`?

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN` on your query and analyze the results.

Comment: `CONCAT` combines all its parameters into one string.  You are only passing it one parameter, so why do you have it?  Did you want `GROUP_CONCAT`, maybe?  Even though it wouldn't make sense since you are using `MIN`.  What *exactly* is this query supposed to do?  What is `_DOP0` supposed to contain?

Comment: It seems to be a running total (sorry, running minimum). Not easy to optimize in MySQL. You can write it using MySQL variables.

Comment: You could try an index on `(dstart1, vresult)` for this query

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about what you're trying to do... this query should return the same results and has been removed the unnecessary calculations:

```
select a.primarykey, a.SID, a.VID, a.topic, a.dstart, a.dstop,
       a.vresult, a.dstart1, a.dstart2, (
           select MIN(d.vresult) 
           from _temp._pb_1_1_4_1 d  
           where  d.dstart1 > a.dstart1) _DOP0 
from _temp._pb_1_1_4_1 a
```

Anyway, it would help to understand what you're trying to do with that query.

Comment: In the question, he says that `dstart1` is an indexed `Date` field.

Comment: Good catch, I got lost in the table names (thought they were different tables) and that only one `dstart1` column might have been indexed (that's why I said `both`)... that makes the inner `select` even more weird and probably unnessary

Comment: Yeah, I got confused too.  Took a while to realize he was joining the same table.  `_temp._pb_1_1_4_1` is a confusing name :)